# Wiremock verify - How to match the request with time parameter

Tags: wiremock

I have time (messageId) parameter in my request.  When i try to wiremock its not matching as expected.  Please let me know how can we match like these scenarios

EX:

messageId =  current date and time in millisec

com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: No requests exactly matched. Most similar request was:  expected:<
POST
/xxx/v2/yyy?apikey=test_key&messageId=**1614515075245**&calculatePromotions=false&origin=yy&siteCode=123&workstationId=0

> but was:<
> POST
> /xxx/v2/yyy?apikey=test_key&messageId=**1614515078010**&calculatePromotions=false&origin=yy&siteCode=123&workstationId=0

Comment: Can you provide the exact setup you're using to attempt to match on the request? What does the stub/mapping look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can match using regex on query parameters, which should solve your issue.

```json
{
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "/xxx/v2/yyy",
    "method": "POST",
    "queryParameters": {
      "api_key": {
        "equalTo": "test_key"
      },
      "messageId": {
        "matches": ".*"
      },
      "calculatePromotions": {
        "equalTo": false
      },
      "origin": {
        "equalTo": "yy"
      },
      "siteCode": {
        "equalTo": 123
      },
      "workstationId": {
        "equalTo": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Let me try and confirm back